# why i cant install my package using pypi and i have error?

Tags: python, module, package, setuptools, setup.py

this is my setup.py for my icaptcha package that can create simple image captcha

```
import pathlib
from setuptools import setup

# The directory containing this file
HERE = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent

# The text of the README file
README = (HERE / "README.md").read_text()

# This call to setup() does all the work
setup(
    name="ICaptcha",
    version="2.0.0",
    description="Create Simple Image Captcha For Normal Use",
    long_description=README,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/imanhpr/ICaptcha",
    author="Iman Hosseini Pour",
    author_email="imanhpr1999@gmail.com",
    license="MIT",
    classifiers=[
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
    ],
    packages=['icaptcha'],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=["pillow"],

)
```

i uploaded it in pypi and when i try to install my package i see this error

```
pip install icaptcha
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement string (from ICaptcha) (from versions: none) 
ERROR: No matching distribution found for string (from ICaptcha)
```

what is this error and how can i fix this ?

Comment: Just to make sure: this seems like a Python3 (3.8) only project, have you double checked that you tried to install it with a Python 3.8 interpreter? `path/to/python3.8 -m pip install ICaptcha`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You uploaded the package to Test PyPI: https://test.pypi.org/project/ICaptcha/

But not to PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/ICaptcha/ returns error 404.

To install from Test PyPI with dependencies from PyPI:

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple/ ICaptcha
```

Or upload to PyPI and repeat

```
pip install ICaptcha
```

Comment: i uploaded it on  pypi but when i see that error i decided to delete it